# Format a table into multiple columns based on some rows/conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to format a new table from below based on certain conditions. Each email column is grouped together. Not sure where to begin.:

```
email              node_id  title
test@gmail.com     123      Some, text 1 
test@gmail.com     456      Some, text 2
test@gmail.com     789      Some, text 3
example@gmail.com  123      Some, text 1
example@gmail.com  767      Some, text 4
example@gmail.com  122      Some, text 5
```

into:

```
email              n1   t1             n2      t2           n3     t3
test@gmail.com     123  Some,text 1   456   Some,text 2    789     Some, text 3 
example@gmail.com  123  Some,text 1   767   Some,text 4    122     Some, test 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a column with `cumcount` so you can `pivot` it, then rename the columns:

```
res = (df.assign(no=df.groupby("email")["node_id"].cumcount()+1)
         .pivot(index="email", columns="no", values=["node_id", "title"]))

res.columns = [x+str(y) for x in ("n", "t") for y in range(1, 4)]

print (res)

                    n1   n2   n3            t1            t2            t3
email                                                                     
example@gmail.com  123  767  122  Some, text 1  Some, text 4  Some, text 5
test@gmail.com     123  456  789  Some, text 1  Some, text 2  Some, text 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['test@gmail.com', 123, "Foo"],
        ['test@gmail.com', 456, "Bar"],
        ['example@gmail.com', 789, "Baz"],
        ['example@gmail.com', 123, "Foo"]],
    columns=['email', 'node_id', 'title'])

df.groupby('email').agg({'node_id': list, 'title': list})
```

In the end it still has one node_id and title column, but the node_ids and titles are collected.

```
                     node_id     title
email       
example@gmail.com   [789, 123]  [Baz, Foo]
test@gmail.com      [123, 456]  [Foo, Bar]
```